# SFMC Tracking of multiple emails for same contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Our architecture requires a contact having multiple emails in salesforce so we created custom email fields on Contact object to capture this and the contacts are synced to SFMC using Contact Builder.

We have few journeys and they get sent to different emails of a contact. I could achieve this by specifying the channel address in Journey builder and the emails are being sent to diffrent addresses based on the channel address.  However tracking results are being synced to Salesforce only for primary email field on contact and I don't see the tracking results for other emails in Salesforce.

Is that a known behavior? Would appreciate your input.